# delete row in my database using php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am trying to delete a row in my database while getting it's id from the url 
for exmaple exmaple.com /deleteTeam.php?Id=? << this is the selected id from radio button option and it will be equal to number when selected like Id=1.

```
include ('connnect.php'); 
// this connect my database and working
$command = "DELETE * FROM SoccerPoll WHERE Id=?";
$stmt = $dbh ->prepare($command);
$stmt->execute($_GET['Id']);
```

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: [That's **not** how `DELETE` works](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: It's just `DELETE FROM...`. You can't delete individual fields. Only the entire row or record (whichever you prefer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bindParam or bindValue before trying to execute que query.

```
$command = " DELETE FROM SoccerPoll WHERE Id=:id LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $dbh ->prepare($command);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['Id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

A delete would be executed in the following way

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE filmID =  :filmID";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':filmID', $_GET['filmID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);   
$stmt->execute();
```